# iPhone Address Book: List Sources and Accounts

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I need to select the address book source in which contacts are created by my app.

In the Contacts app, when I select "< Groups", I get the options

- **All Contacts**
- **MobileMe**

  - All MobileMe
  - Company
  - Family
  - Friends
  - …
- **ACME Exchange**

  - ACME Exchange Global Address List
- **Test CardDAV**

  - Addressbook
  - Search

Using the function `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources` I get source records for

- No name; type: kABSourceTypeMobileMe
- No name; type: kABSourceTypeExchangeGAL
- "Addressbook"; type: kABSourceTypeCardDAV
- "Search"; type: kABSourceTypeCardDAVSearch

The names are in no way descriptive and I would like to show the account names in addition to the source name or type, just like the Contact app does.

Do you know a way to find out the account name of a source, or to retrieve all existing account names and the sources of each account? Any other ideas to get more descriptive entries?

Comment: Did you find out, how to list the account names? i.e. in your example: ACME Exchange or Test CardDAV

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 5.1 there is no public API for this.

One would hope that `ABRecordCopyCompositeName()` would get what you're after — it provides the "human friendly" name for Person and Group records — but alas it returns null.

As Graham pointed out (when offering a bounty) directly asking for `kABSourceNameProperty` provides the wrong answer.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef sources = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources(addressBook);

CFIndex i, c = CFArrayGetCount(sources);
ABRecordRef curSource;

// Log each source name.
for (i=0; i<c; i++) {
    curSource = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sources, i);
    NSString *name = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(curSource);
    NSLog(@"Alas this is null: %@", name);


    NSString *directValue = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(curSource,kABSourceNameProperty);
    NSLog(@"And direct access gives wrong answer: %@", directValue);

}

CFRelease(sources);
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

All I can suggest is filing a Radar to ask that `ABRecordCopyCompositeName()` be made to make whatever service Contacts itself is using available to the rest of us.

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately `ABRecordCopyCompositeName()`'s documentation includes "The behavior of this function is not defined for source records." so I wasn't expecting it to work :-(

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

[Obtaining Specific ABSource from ABAddressBook in iOS 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679641/obtaining-specific-absource-from-abaddressbook-in-ios-4)

iOS 4+ provides new API that allows one to select a specific `ABSource` from the `ABAddressBook`. This may be useful as some operations, e.g. creating an `ABGroup`, are not supported in some sources (i.e. Exchange).

"Not all source types support groups, more conspicuously, Exchange does not know anything about groups." - http://flavors.me/volonbolon#1a5/tumblr

It shows how functions can be used that leverage the new API to obtain sources of specific types which may be used in calls to `ABGroupCreateInSource()`, which looks to be what you're after.